# What is reason for doing IIS reset?

Tags: c#, silverlight, iis, windows-server-2008

I have created an silverlight application and services. After i published it in 
IIS(Win Xp or Win server 2003), i need to do an IIS reset to access that app. What may be the reasons?

Thanx in advance

Comment: Doing an IIS reset is like when [Fonzie hits the Jukebox](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3NxGO2lx-A0).

Comment: @mhn: Are you talking about in general, or are you thinking that it should be able to hot-publish in this specific case, without restarting the IIS service, and is for some reason broken?

Comment: What happens if you don't reset IIS? Error?

Comment: @Merlyn: I am talikin abt this case. Bcoz i think some of the API's am using in code, is making me too do an IIS reset after i publish. But i don know exactly wat is it?

Comment: @Olivier: I am gettin an "Service Unavailable" error msg

Comment: @mhn: If that is the case, I recommend you add more detail to your question, showing what you have tried that *does* work.  For example, if you create a super bare bones application/service and publish it, do you have to IIS reset?  If that does work, then I'm thinking you're also going to have to provide a ton more info about yoru specific app for us to have a chance to resolve this problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider any Asp.net application deployed with some javascript version 1.0 and then after in development you changed the script and re-deployed ,if user don't hit refresh button,asp.net website will keep continue using script 1.0 ,so in this case either we ask user to hit refresh or else change the script version to 1.1 and re-deployed.As it was cached at client (browser)

Silverlight itself is client-side technology,when we request for any silverlight application it downloaded the xap folder (including dlls,client-side code).

Give try ,once you again deploy the Silverlight on IIS. Just Refresh the url,clear browser cache and see,it should work without IIS Reset.